# Are design patterns paradigm specific?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

I've been looking alot into design paterns lately, and really took in O'Reily's *Head First Design Patterns*.  The languague the book chooses to use, however, is Java where I mainly work in .Net.  There's actually a post on SO that talks about the book being addapted to c++ with little to know propblems, and I find that many of patterns shown for Java can also be used in other OO languages like .Net or C++.  Granted, when I hear design patterns, I assume object oriented languages.  But I realize that design patterns exist across other paradigms like procedural oriented languages, etc.  **Is it safe to assume that design patterns are paradigm specific as opposed to being technology specific?**  Are there paterns that work for Java that don't for .Net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Design patterns are common solutions to problems that arise from degenerate problem-solving strategies and poorly designed languages. The design patterns you’re familiar with are specific to the mischaracterisation of the object-oriented paradigm embodied by Java, C#, and many other languages. So yes, design patterns are paradigm-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all the design patterns are builded with consideration of OOPs funda. So, we can implement design patterns in any language that supports basic oops property.

In short it is not language or framework specific. It is just blue print which can be followed to build any kind of building(Keep in mind OOPs basic properties).